# Perl hash substitution with special characters in keys

Tags: regex, perl, hashtable, substitution, string-substitution

My current script will take an expression, ex:

```
my $expression = '( a || b || c )';
```

and go through each boolean combination of inputs using sub/replace, like so:

```
my $keys = join '|', keys %stimhash;
$expression =~ s/($keys)\b/$stimhash{$1}/g;
```

So for example expression may hold,

```
( 0 || 1 || 0 )
```

This works great.

However, I would like to allow the variables (also in %stimhash) to contain a tag, *.

```
my $expression = '( a* || b* || c* )';
```

Also, printing the keys of the stimhash returns:

```
a*|b*|c*
```

It is not properly substituting/replacing with the extra special character, *.
It gives this warning:

> Use of uninitialized value within %stimhash in substitution iterator

I tried using quotemeta() but did not have good results so far.
It will drop the values.  An example after the substitution looks like:

```
( * || * || * )
```

Any suggestions are appreciated,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem 1

You use the pattern `a*` thinking it will match only `a*`, but `a*` means "0 or more `a`". You can use `quotemeta` to convert text into a regex pattern that matches that text.

Replace

```
my $keys = join '|', keys %stimhash;
```

with

```
my $keys = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %stimhash;
```

### Problem 2

```
\b
```

is basically

```
(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w)
```

But `*` (like the space) isn't a word character. The solution might be to replace

```
s/($keys)\b/$stimhash{$1}/g
```

with

```
s/($keys)(?![\w*])/$stimhash{$1}/g
```

though the following make more sense to me

```
s/(?<![\w*])($keys)(?![\w*])/$stimhash{$1}/g
```

Personally, I'd use

```
s{([\w*]+)}{ $stimhash{$1} // $1 }eg
```

Comment: Thanks for the very informative post.  This solved the problem (and a few others).